# Dynamic string array in C with malloc and realloc won't exit a loop

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I've been trying to make a simple console application in C (using dev-c++) that reads characters and places them in an array while dynamically lengthening the array to accomodate for as many characters as you want until you press enter. The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
   int x=0;
   char * ch1;
   ch1 = (char*) malloc(1);

   do
   {
      ch1[x] = getche();
      x++;
      ch1 = (char*) realloc (ch1,x);
   } while (ch1[x-1]!='\n');

   printf("Input Sentence  Is :%s",ch1);
   free(ch1);
}
```

while the program executes fine with no errors, after you type your sentence and press enter instead of simply printing your sentence the 'cursor' shifts back to the begining of the window and you can keep typing above the previous characters.

Edit: I know this is not an optimal way to do it since you lose the backspace ability for example i just wanted to see if it would work after we were taught malloc and realloc today.

Comment: Strings need a terminating null in C. You are also allocating too few characters each time - `x` will be `1` at your first `realloc()`, for instance. Don't cast the return from either allocation function, and `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths That's only going to be a problem when he gets to the `printf()`, though. My bet is `getche()` is returning the enter key as `'\r'` instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: Also, the first `realloc` will read as `realloc(ch1, 1)`, because `x==1`. You should `realloc(ch1, x+1)`.

Comment: Huh.. switching (ch1[x-1]!='\n') to (ch1[x-1]!='\r') as well as turning the x in realloc to x+1
Actually did the trick but the return value is some random number so

Excuse me if the question is stupid but since i am fairly new to these commands could you explain in more simple terms what exactly i did wrong with realloc?
I understand the part about x being too small each time but what do you mean by " Don't cast the return from either allocation function, and main() returns int" ?

Comment: @user3669817: It should be `int main(void)`, not `main()`, and it should be `ch1 = malloc(1);`, not `ch1 = (char*) malloc(1);`. You should also be checking the return value of both of those functions, since they can both fail. Casting the return is technically not wrong, but it's considered bad form. Declaring `main()` in the way you did is technically wrong.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. One final question though. Using malloc do you have to manually add '\0' at the last spot in the array or is it added by default when calling malloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm all-but-certain this is what you're *trying* to do. The difference between it and your code should be obvious:

- Uses `calloc()` for the initial buffer to ensure it is terminated,
- Checks for input stream EOF as well as CR and LF chars.
- `x` represents the buffer length, not the string length.
- String termination is established on each successful expansion.
- Memory allocation failures are accounted.
- Standard-compliant declaration of `main()`,
- Uses the standard-compliant `getchar()` for input.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ch1 = calloc(1,1), *tmp;
    size_t x = 1;
    int c;

    if (!ch1)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate string buffer.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\r' && c != '\n')
    {
        tmp = realloc(ch1, x+1);
        if (!tmp)
        {
            // note: the string at ch1 still valid.
            perror("Failed to resize string buffer.");
            break;
        }

        ch1 = tmp;
        ch1[x - 1] = c;
        ch1[x++] = 0;
    }

    printf("Input Sentence: %s\n", ch1);
    free(ch1);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This certainly cleans it up a lot. As a matter of personal choice I would let `x == strlen(ch1)` at any time - so I would start with `x=0`, then use `realloc(ch1, x+2);` and `ch1[x++]=c; ch1[x++]='\0';` . And I would use `'\0'` not '0' although I know they are the same. Just because I'm a picky so-and-so.

Comment: @Floris I use `0` because it always works and you *never* have to replace all your `'\0'` with `L'\0'` when doing a unicode wide-char port. Yeah, I'm just that lazy. And it is indeed a matter of taste regarding whether x is the string len or x is the buffer len. In this case it can be either since they're always one-off from each other. I prefer buffer len, but others (ex: yourself) differ.

Comment: Yes this does exactly what i wanted.. although it uses quite a few things i haven't learned yet but its only a little so i can snoop around to see what everything does. Thanks for taking the time to aswer

Answer (score 0):

On my current system (SUSE SLES-11) I can't compile this due to the non-portable `conio.h`. Here's my solution;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
   {
   int     rCode   = 0;
   char   *buf     = NULL;
   size_t  bufSize = 0;
   int     done    = 0;

   /* Allocate a single byte to hold a string-termination 
    * character '\0' 
    */
   errno=0;
   buf = malloc(bufSize + 1);
   if(NULL == buf)
      {
      rCode=errno?errno:ENOMEM;
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed. errno=%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   ++bufSize;
   buf[0] = '\0';

   /** Loop until done. **/
   while(!done)
      {
      char *tmp;          /* Used to safely realloc(). */
      int ch = getche();  /* read the next character. */
      switch(ch)
         {
         case '\r':       /* Check for end-of-line characters. */
         case '\n':       /*  (I agree with Paul Z's comment. */
            done = (-1);  /* TRUE */

            /* Do not include these characters in the final buffer. */
            continue;     

         default:
            /* Change the last character of the buf from '\0' to ch. */
            buf[bufSize] = ch;  

            /* Increase the size of buf so that a new '\0' character can
             * be appended. 
             */
            errno=0;
            tmp=realloc(buf, bufSize+1);
            if(NULL == tmp)
               {
               rCode=errno?errno:ENOMEM;
               fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
               goto CLEANUP;
               }
            buf=tmp;         // EDIT (Thanks Floris for catching this!)
            buf[bufSize++] = '\0';
            break;
         }
      }

   printf("Input Sentence Is: %s\n", buf);

CLEANUP:

   if(buf)
      free(buf);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: Mostly correct - but shouldn't you set `buf` equal to `tmp` once you confirm that the reallocation was successful? From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/: `Changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.

The function may move the memory block to a new location (whose address is returned by the function).`

Comment: I know you said you can't compile it, but several errors in this code, including `if(NULL == malloc)`, declaring `bufSize` but actually using `bufLen`, no return type for `main()`, as well as style issues including setting `bufSize` to `0` and then having the two next references to it being `bufSize + 1` and then `++bufSize` meaning it should have been `1` to begin with, egregiously unnecessary use of `goto` and Yoda conditions, and returning non-portable values from `main()` which has the side-effect of effectively returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` if `malloc()` doesn't set `errno`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, wow... I think I should have just posted pseudo-code (or perhaps that is what I ended up doing).  [√]`if(NULL == malloc)`, [√]`bufLen::bufSize`, [√]`int main()` fixed.  I understand your point about initializing `bufsize`; my practice is to try not to increment bufSize until the buffer has has actually been successfully realloc'ed.  As for `malloc()` not setting errno; that is a possibility; I'll fix that in the answer.  Thank you for your comment; very helpful.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths; oh... as for `goto`; The reason (IMHO) it exists in C is to handle exceptions (and perhaps for some state machine methods).  I use `goto` specifically, and correctly; but I do understand your position.  ...`Yoda conditions`?

Comment: In a short program like this, a "goto" for handling all the errors isn't such a terrible thing to do - but then again, you could just have a `return ENOMEM;` statement since the OS will free all the memory for you.

Comment: @Floris, understood; and you are of course correct; but it overlooks `Rule #1` on the _Mahonri list of rules for writing maintainable code:_ **A function shall have only one return.**

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: Yoda conditions are when you put the condition backwards, such as `if ( NULL == ptr )` as a result of not trusting your compiler. I know you use goto deliberately. Others - including you - may disagree, but I just find that peppering an answer with stylistic practices that are at best questionable detracts from the actual answer itself. Compared to the relative simplicity and clarity of the other answer to this question, for instance, which is at an absolute minimum no less correct.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths. 'Yoda'... Ok.  I actually picked up the practice in 1993 from the book `"Writing Solid Code" --Steve Maguire`.  And so you know, I use `Yoda conditions` because `I trust my compiler`, not because of `not trusting' my compiler; and it's an excellent habit.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: That's a matter of opinion. Any compiler worth its salt will warn you about potentially troublesome assignments within conditions, so unless you ignore your warnings it's at best unnecessary, and comes at the cost of reducing readability and causing confusion. These are all questions of personal preference, so there are no rights or wrongs, but I think it's a rather obnoxious habit, regardless of whether some popular books promote it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths.  You are absolutely correct; its a matter of opinion.

Comment: As for the "number one rule". My rule is - as soon as you know it is time to leave, leave. I see no added value in `errNum=1; goto exit; exit: return errNum;` vs `return 1;`. But again, it's probably a matter of opinion.